# Effect to audio and video file

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, core-audio

In my app I want to give effect to audio and video file like it is given to  **Pheed** Application. I want to mix audio recorded sound with predefine clips. And also want to give sound different effect like echo , surrounding Normal , And with video file I want to add different effects like sepia,.. I don't know which class library I have to use to implement6 this . Can any one suggest me any library for that or any way how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a pair of libraries you can try:

For **audio** filters and effects you can try with [The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/). It is build on top of Core Audio.

For **video** effects try [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). I haven't tried it but it is supposed to work better than Core Image when handling videos.

Comment: how can I give real-time(instant) effect to video? like LINE snapmovie app??